# How to check server response before saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using react-redux with redux-saga to handle my async api calls in a React application. it basically looks like this :
Saga file

```js
function* getStuffEffect(action){
    try{
        yield put({type:'REQUEST',payload:[]});
        //requestFunction(url,type,token) uses axios
        const data = yield call(requestFunciotn,'/profile','GET',action.payload.token)
        if(data.status>=200&data.status<300){
            yield put({type:'SUCCESS',payload:data.data})
        }else{
            yield put({type:'FAILURE',payload:data.message})
        }
    catch(err){
        yield put({type:'FAILURE',payload:err.response.message})
    }
}

export default function* watch(){
    yield all([
        //...other effects,
        takeLatest('GET_STUFF_CONSTANT',getStuffEffect)
    ])
}
```

store file

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootSaga from '../sagas'

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const middlewares = [otherMiddleares,sagaMiddleware].filter(Boolean);

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(...middlewares)(createStore);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

And now to The question: there are times that api will respond with 401 caused by invalid token. I am looking for a way to handle this before it reaches the catch phrase of the above saga and redirect the user to the login page. I now that this can be done inside the component and after updating like this:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(this.props.reducer.someFlag){
        this.props.history.push('/login')
    }
}
```

but i'm looking for a more reliable solution. I have a feeling that the answer should be using middlewares, but i dont know how. so any help would be great. tnx.

Comment: you can use the history object to push the route in saga itself, meanwhile throw an error for the user to understand that they are not authenticated

Comment: @humanbean tnx for the reply. That is a good way of doing it but i have more than one or two sagas and there must be a better way than putting 4 lines of code in all of them.

Comment: you can create an HOC to check for authentication and wrap the component within it.
HOC checks for authentication and returns the desired component otherwise routes the user to login page.

Comment: @humanbean this is a good idea. ill check it out. thank you.